# Android, проблема с SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment, android-sqlite

`DBHelper = new AppSQLiteHelper(this);`
`AppSQLiteHelper` это класс, который наследуется от `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
Проблема в этой строчке, делаю приложение с разными окнами, с меню в нижней панели. При создании экземпляра в классе фрагмента ошибка:
`Required type: Context | Provided: Notification Fragment`.
Сам код не находится в `MainActivity`. Не понимаю, что нужно положить в скобки или какие изменения требуется внести в класс `AppSQLiteHelper`, чтобы получилось создать объект. Прошу не кидаться камнями, не очень в этом опытный. Хотелось бы получить более развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Required type: Context` - нужен объект наследника класса `Context`.
Основными наследниками являются `Application`, `Activity`, `Service` и их потомки соответственно.
Во фрагменте контекст можно получить методами `getContext()` и `requireContext()`.
Активити: `getActivity()` и `requireActivity()`

```java
DBHelper = new AppSQLiteHelper(requireContext());
```